# Rails - How to download .pdf file using Grape API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

In rails 4, I am using `grape` gem for mobile app features. In mobile app, I need to provide download `.pdf` file option. I have referred this [How to allow Binary File download using GRAPE API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641388/how-to-allow-binary-file-download-using-grape-api#answer-19898620) but file is not generating here.

Other than mobile app(in web side) I have downloading a file using,

```
file_path = "#{Rails.root}/public/downloads/#{@user.id}_guide.pdf"
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(render_to_string('public/guide/template', :layout=> false))
File.open(file_path, 'wb') do |file|
  file << pdf
end
return file_path
```

Please help me to write an API which generates and downloads a `.pdf` file

Comment: You are just returning a String that represents the path to the file. You need to actually read out that file eg. `File.open(file_path,&:read)` as well as set the appropriate headers for the MIME type and disposition. Read the post you are referencing and it will solve this for you..

Comment: As per the reference, file is not generating. How to generate .pdf file?